# Problem loading ~/.ideavimrc from PyCharm

Tags: vim, pycharm, ide, ideavim

I installed PyCharm on Ubuntu 18.04 by extracting the tarball into `/etc/` and creating a shortcut through the Tools menu.

I installed IdeaVim through the marketplace, and the Vim plug-in is working as expected.

Now I want to import my vim settings from my `.vimrc`. I just copied the `.vimrc` to `~/.ideavimrc` and reloaded my IDE. However, my remappings are not working. I tried sourcing the rc file using `:source ~/.ideavimrc`, but this doesn't work either.

The only content of my `.ideavimrc` file is this line:

```
xnoremap p pgvy
```

I really hate the paste-setting of vim, so I need this remapping and I'm lost. Thanks for the help.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/src/main/java/com/maddyhome/idea/vim/package-info.java#L684-L695) `xnoremap` is not supported. Try `vnoremap` instead. (And consider using their issue tracker in the future.)

Comment: I tried it with `vnoremap` but still no success. But will add this to the issue tracking. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how `xnoremap p pgvy` is supposed to work, but `noremap` works for me in my `.ideavimrc`. You could try remapping something you don't use often (`P`?).

Comment: @nanotek this was an actual bug with `xnoremap` and has been resolved by now: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an actual bug with Idea VIM plugin and the `.ideavimrc` file, found [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2491).

It has been resolved since.